# Download File to local from S3 Generated URL

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a `Node.js` application which gives me a url to download files from S3. (i.e. `http://example.com/download/1`) and the application will return generated url to download the file.

The problem is I am not getting the correct file while using the code below to download file.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var options;

options = {
    host: 'example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/download/1',
    headers: {
        "USERNAME":"test@example.com",
        "PASSWORD":"testpassword"
    }
}

var file = fs.createWriteStream("sample.jpg");
var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.pipe(file);
});
```

I am new to `Node.js`. Please let if know if there are something I am doing wrong.

Comment: is '/download/1, a typo, or did you really forget to close the path string?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: @Manube sorry, it was my typo in question here. It download file, but it said contain errors. But if I download directly file from S3 using Cyberduck, it is cool. I really have no idea about it :/